# How to remove row gap between two tables in Laravel maatwebsite/excel FromView

Tags: excel, laravel, export, laravel-blade, laravel-excel

I want to export order and order item data in my laravel web app in xls format so i decided to try  using maatwebsite/excel v3.1. I'm using `FromView` class to convert blade template into an excel file, the blade structure looks like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th> Order# </th>
     <th> Customer </th>
     <th> Order Date </th>
     <th> Total </th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> 1132 </td> 
     <td> Ashin </td> 
     <td> 21-11-2021 </td> 
     <td> 3000.00$ </td> 
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th colspan="4"> Order Items </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th> Product </th>
     <th> Price </th>
     <th> Qty </th>
     <th> Subtotal </th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> Bag </td> 
     <td> 1200.00$ </td> 
     <td> 2 </td> 
     <td> 2400.00$ </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> Hat </td> 
     <td> 600.00$ </td> 
     <td> 1 </td> 
     <td> 600.00$ </td> 
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and the results looks like this:

[image]

there is a row gap between these two tables, how can i remove it?

Comment: It is put because there are two different tables do you want to override this feature?

Comment: yes correct @bhucho